# Using Customer.io how to send 2 different emails simultaneously to two different users at the same time.

Tags: javascript, api, email

As the title states, I want to send two different emails, simultaneously to two different users. 
I am using JavaScript for the API.

I also would like to know how can I send delayed emails, on custom dates. Currently we can do that from the dashboard, but that allows to fix days / weeks. But what I'm looking for is to calculate the dates and add a custom date delay that can't be predefined as given in the dashboard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem has been solved. 
I created two separate API calls for each customer. Using switch statement and while loop

```
switch(customer){
    while(counter > 0){
        case 1:
            //Make first API call  
           //_cio.identify
           _cio.identify({
               // Required attributes
               id: id,           // Unique id for the currently signed in user in your application.
               email: yourEmail, // Email of the currently signed in user.
               created_at: time,   // Timestamp in your system that represents when
                            // the user first signed up. You'll want to send it
                            // as seconds since the epoch.

  // Optional (these are examples. You can name attributes what you wish)

              task: task,
              supervisor_email: supervisorEmail,       // Add any attributes you'd like to use in the email subject or body.
              goal_date: date,      // To use the example segments, set this to 'free' or 'premium'.
             user_name: name,
             supervisor_name: supervisorName,
             goal_setter: isUser,
             pay: pay

         });

          customer = 2;
        break;

       case 2:
           //Make the second API call
           break;

      counter--;

    }
}
```